# Mixed DML operation error

Tags: apex, unit-test, error, user, roles

I am facing Mixed DML error in the following case:

```
static testmethod void method1()
{
    User u1 = DataFactory.createUser('testUser','test@user.com','permissionSetAPIname');  

    Obj1 rec1 = DataFactory.createrec1('Record1');
    insert rec1;

    Obj2 rec2 = DataFactory.createrec2('Rec2',rec1,system.today()-10, system.today()+10 );
    insert rec2; 

    Obj3 rec3 = DataFactory.createrec3(rec2,'Tester',u1,'US');
    insert Role;

    test.starttest();   

    //testing code

    test.stoptest();

}
```

However the following is working fine

```
static testmethod void method1()
{
     User u1 = new User(Alias = 'testRole',
                  Email             = 'role@test.com',
                  EmailEncodingKey  = 'UTF-8',
                  LastName          = 'user',
                  FirstName         = 'test',
                  LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
                  LocaleSidKey      = 'en_US',
                  ProfileId         = [select Id from Profile where Name = 'Basic User' limit 1].Id,
                  TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Chicago',
                  Username          = 'stakeholder@test' + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000) + '.com',
                  UserRoleId        = null,
                  Country           = 'Great Britain');
    insert u1;   

    Obj1 rec1 = DataFactory.createrec1('Record1');
    insert rec1;

    Obj2 rec2 = DataFactory.createrec2('Rec2',rec1,system.today()-10, system.today()+10 );
    insert rec2; 

    Obj3 rec3 = DataFactory.createrec3(rec2,'Tester',u1,'US');
    insert Role;

    test.starttest();   

    //testing code

    test.stoptest();

}
```

Please explain the difference. As my understanding is that transaction remains the same in both the cases.

Answer (score 8):

You must specify `UserRoleId` as `null`. [Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm):

> You can insert a user in a transaction with other sObjects in Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 15.0 and later if UserRoleId is specified as null.

The obvious conclusion is that your `DataFactory.createUser` method is setting the `UserRoleId` to some other value.

---

If you must specify this field for some reason, you need to isolate your `User` creation in a separate [transaction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction.htm). One way to cross the boundary into a separate transaction is to enter or leave a `system.runAs` block.  The only logic in this separate transaction should be to `insert` any `User` records.

```
//  set up User records
system.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId()))
{
    insert userRecords;
}
// other setup
```

Note that since only admins can create `User` records, it may be best to query for one so the test will work regardless of who runs it.

```
User SYS_ADMIN = [
    SELECT Id FROM User WHERE IsActive = true
    AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
];
system.runAs(SYS_ADMIN) { /*logic*/ }
```

Comment: Hey Adrian . Your inputs helped. I however have failed to understand the difference between the two cases. How does putting system.runAs(currentUser) differ from not putting anything. In both cases the test class runs in system mode, that is current user mode.

Comment: @star check out the link on how transactions work.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your test setup in a `System.runAs()` block to avoid this.

e.g.

```
User thisUser = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];

System.runAs(thisUser) {
    // perform necessary setup/testing here
}
```

This method is referenced in the `Apex Developer Guide` linked [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects_test_methods.htm)

Specifically noted: `These techniques enable you, for example, to create a user with a role and other sObjects in the same test.`